# Как отключать и включать slick-carousel на разных разрешениях?

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, slick.js

Использую слайдер [slick-carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). Часто бывает необходимо отключать слайдер на определенных разрешениях, помогает в этом такая конструкция:

```
responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 767,
            settings: "unslick"
        } 
]
```

Но это полезно если нужно отключить уже действующий слайдер, а если нужно сделать наоборот чтобы слайдер на десктопах не работал а на мобильных включался то возникают сложности. Есть ли возможность использовать этот метод наоборот? Чтобы не писать конструкцию типа:

```
var width = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function(){
  if( width < 767) {
    $(".slider").slick({...});
  }}
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Укажите breakpoint для широкого экрана (для desktop), например:

```
responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 2048,
                settings: "unslick"
            },
            {
               breakpoint: 600,
               settings: {
                  slidesToShow: 2,
                  slidesToScroll: 2
            }
        },
    ]
```

Comment: Я как раз сейчас так делаю, "breakpoint: 9999" но думаю что есть более красивый способ.

Comment: Куда уж красивее. Оба варианта работают с событием $(window).resize()

Comment: Ну я имел в виду что может свойство unslick можно указать в дефолтных параметрах слайдера чтоб не писать его в массиве responsive, но если такой возможности нет, то этот вариант самый привлекательный.